# How to avoid UrlReferrer error in asp .net when page called using javascript window.open

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have two aspx pages with names List.aspx & View.aspx .

In view.apsx am using Request.UrlReferrer property (For some security purpose)

```
View.aspx
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Request.UrlReferrer Is Nothing Then
        Response.Write("Invalid URL")
    Else
      // Some Code here
    End

End Sub
```

In List.aspx page call one java script function such as:

```
List.aspx 
    function ViewDetail(HCode)
    {
            var url = "View.aspx?ActivePageName=V&HeaderCode=" + HCode;
                var z = window.open(url, "Action", "toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=0,border=thin,top=400,left=400,width=500,height=200");
    }
```

In new opened pop up window, I got the UrlReferrer is error.

Comment: I just make a test and to me is working fine. (do you have note a space here ?-> `" List.aspx`) even with the space is work.

Comment: Yes I make the same code as this one and its work to me - but note, that the `Request.UrlReferrer` must be on the `list.aspx` NOT on `view.aspx` as you type

Comment: Please again read my question 2nd line.. Request.UrlReferrer is using in view.aspx not in list.aspx

Comment: Do you see that on `list.aspx` you open the `list.aspx` using javascript ?. The `view.aspx` how is involve on that and on UrlReferrer ?

Comment: Extremely sorry for this .. I am wrongly prepare the sample code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I would try to discourage you for using UrlReferrer for security purposes. Idea behind this is you can call your page only from page on your domain. This is better achievable trough cookies as UrlReferrer has a browser-specific behaviour. Chrome or Firefox can process this differently than Internet Explorer.

There is a similar question on SO that lead to nowhere:
 [URL Referer not working on pop up windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580613/url-referer-not-working-on-pop-up-windows)

What I would do if I were you - as part of

```
var url = "View.aspx?ActivePageName=V&HeaderCode=" + HCode + "&Token=<%= EncryptedToken %>";
```

I would pass some security token, that will contain page name, Like (C#) :

```
string EncryptedToken { get {
  return Encrypt(string.Format("/List.aspx,{0}", DateTime.Now.Ticks));
}}
```

And on View.aspx (aside from UrlReferrer) check if there is encrypted token in query string, if it can be decrypted and isn't too old.